# Color Swatch Image is not rendering

Tags: php, html, css, magento, magento-1.9

I am using magento rwd package and default theme.

- Color Attribute has options 'Black'
- media/wysiwyg/swatches has 'black.png' image with correct permission
- In admin panel configuration it is enabled with size 21 X 21
  But, why in front end it is not rendering. If you see this image color swatcher is working fine but only thing is img src is missing.

what i am missing ? Can you help in it.

[image: color swatch image missing **strong text**]

Comment: Use template hints to trace the source of the phtml and see why null value is being echoed. Alternatevly post some code or link to website.

Comment: with permission 0777 to /media it is working fine, but not with 0700. Is it okay to give 0777 to /media directory in magento?

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid 0777 permission only if it's very very necessary.
Use 0770 for directories and 0640 for file. Alternatevely use 0755 and 0644.

Hope it helps.